InnerShadow effect not being applied in qml application
I create a InnerShadow effect using Qt Quick Effect Maker, preview seems to be working fine.

but when I am trying to implement this effect into my QML application it is not being reflected there.

I exported this effect with both options Qt 6 Compatibility and Qt Latest but it is still not working.
I am using:

PySide6
Qt 6.5.3
Qt Creator 10.0.2

Here is the simple page I am trying to build.
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Effects

import "widgets"
import "effects/InnerShadow"

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    color: "#ffffff"

    Rectangle {
        id: background
        color: "#ffffff"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    InnerShadow{
        id: shadow
        source: background
        anchors.fill: background
    }
}


Here are nodes for this effect.

I tried exporting the effect in different modes and also tried comparing my effect from examples provided
I still wonder that even when there is no error and even preview is fine then why it's not working. Please guide me through this, i will really thankful to you.
Thank you in advance.

Try to follow this example https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickeffectmaker-wiggly-example.html My guess is that some of the resource are missing or aren't correctly referenced. Do you have the *.qsb files in place? What is the content of effects/InnerShadow?

It's really hard to answer this without knowing the definition of InnerShadow. My initial guess would be maybe it's a color issue? How does it decide what color the shadow should be? Does it make a difference if you change the color of your source Rectangle?

@iam_peter the content inside effects/InnerShadow is BlurHelper.qml bluritem.frag.qsb bluritem.vert.qsb innershadow.frag.qsb innershadow.vert.qsb and InnerShadow.qml InnerShadow.qep

@JarMan Added effect definition in question

Does something change if you set layer.enabled: true on background?

@iam_peter No, it doesn't seem to change anything.
